# Is there a way to increase Excel’s CPU usage in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

When I was running an Excel sub which had been taking 30 plus minutes, I noticed that in Task Manager, Excel only used anywhere from 35 to 55% of CPU.

I believe if the CPU usage had been increased somehow, the process would have taken less time. Is there a way to increase Excel's — or any apps for that matter — CPU usage?

I'm running 64-bit Office on 64-bit Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: If you are not running 64-bit Excel on a 64-bit Windows operating system then uninstall Excel (i.e. Office). Reinstall Window as 64-bit if it isn't already 64-bit then install 64-bit Office. Office defaults to a 32-bit install so be sure to use the correct procedure for true 64-bit Office running completely from local hard drive.

Comment: I'm running 64-bit Office on 64-bit Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you seek isn't the one you want, unfortunately.

While Excel sheets are calculated on multiple threads and can utilise up to 100% of your CPU, Excel macros are run on a single thread only.

If most of the processing is unavoidably taking place within VBA, the code may be able to be modified to improve performance.

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity for improvement for Microsoft.

Comment: @joehua I'm sorry...?  Did you use the word "improvement" and "Microsoft" in the same sentence?

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact issue even when I was NOT running a macro/sub and solved it.   Perhaps others may have my similar issue and need a solution to it. Task Manager was showing Excel using only around 10% of my CPU for an EXTREMELY large and VERY formula-intensive spreadsheet.  It was taking 5 minutes to calculate when I initiated it (I use manual calc mode).  Even worse, inserting a row in a table took hours.  I am running Excel 365 64-bit.

I did two things that solved it.  Perhaps it was the second step below (increasing Excel priority) that solved it alone, I am not sure.  That step is suggested above and seems it did not solve it for speeding up macro processing for others, so I am assuming it might not have helped me either (if I had done that alone).  I read this thread late in my attempts to solve this problem and did not try step two alone (or first).  If that does not work for you, then try all the steps below.   It may be the combination that is the ticket.

1. Make sure that you have your "Maximum Processor State" set to 100% under "Processor Power Management" under "Advanced Settings" of "Power Options" of your currently selected "Power Plan" settings.   If you do not see the Processor Power Management settings under your advanced settings of you power plan, then you will have to add it.  See this link to "Why am I missing the processor power management under my power options?" for instructions how to do this:   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-am-i-missing-the-processor-power-management/f5e30954-1843-464e-838b-015cc21d3ebd . I had to do this including modifying my registry.  Note: When I first went to modify my registry, I could not add the Attributes DWORD where specified.  So I ran the editor in Administrator Mode (though this did not seem to work at first either.... but then it did when I tried again... I don't know why).
2. Set your Priority for Excel to High in task manager following the instruction IUnknown gave above.
3. I did not need to do this as Excel was already set to this for me.  However, you should be sure your Excel ribbon "File/Options/Advanced/Formulas/Enable Multi-threaded calculation setting" is set to "Use all processors on this computer".  In my case this was 16.

Excel CPU usage then jumped to 98% in Task Manager!  I hope this helps someone with this problem when simply calculating their spreadsheet (i.e., the problem is not macro-related).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the process priority for any application including Excel. To do this:

1. Open Task Manager
2. Locate Microsoft Excel under Apps
   [image]
3. Right Click, go to Details
   [image]
4. In the Details Tab, right click Excel.Exe again and in the pop up menu Set the 
   priority to High. (You can also go Realtime but that's too high)
   [image]

Comment: Is the effect permanent or I need to do it every time I run Excel?

Comment: While the information in your answer is correct, it likely won't solve the problem.

Comment: Plus 1 because I do this.